# Calender isn't mark for offline usage problem

Tags: evolution

I am using evolution. there is an error message in there saying Error Loading Calender. Calender isn't marked for offline usage. How Do I mark It for offline use? I don't see any box..

Answer (score 0):

1. Create New Calendar
2. Select Google (as the type)
3. add your username etc.
4. select the offline availability option

Comment: I have selected yahoo calender. but where is the offline availability option? I dont see it..  and it's also crashing repeatedly ..